# How is this false?

Tags: expression-test

Why is the result of this False? Am I blind?

```
k *t^2/(2 * t) + k /(2 * t) === (k * t^2 + k)/(2 * t)
```

> False

Comment: `SameQ` vs. `Equal`.  Use `==` instead of `===`.  The triple `===` is used to test if they are the same expression.  It does not test mathematical equivalence.  Read the "Background & Context" of [SameQ](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameQ.html) for more discussion.

Comment: If you want `True`, then I'd suggest `Simplify[difference] == 0`.  -- BTW, folks generally prefer code to be posted than images. It makes it easier for them to test their ideas on your example(s).

Comment: @MichaelE2 `==` or `Equal` does not give a True/False output. It gives [this](https://i.imgur.com/YXEda9n.png) uninformative output. I can put any [rubbish](https://i.imgur.com/3hEn3bj.png) in there and it would show it the same.

Comment: `Simplify[k*t^2/(2 t) + k/(2 t) == (k*t^2 + k)/(2*t)]` gives `True`. You need to put the expressions into the same form to compare them.

Comment: I did have a suggestion.  Did you see it?  (Actually, two, but I mean the `Simplify` one.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Testing equivalence of analytical expressions like $x^2 -x == x(x-1)$](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115303/testing-equivalence-of-analytical-expressions-like-x2-x-xx-1)

Answer (score 1):

```
Reduce[k*t^2/(2*t) + k/(2*t) == (k*t^2 + k)/(2*t)]

(* True *)
```